# El css no está funcionando como esperaba

Tags: html, css

les explico, estoy haciendo un boton GO-UP, el cual funciona correctamente si uso la hoja de estilos en forma de etiqueta `<style>` en el `<head>` del html, pero si quiero hacerlo en un archivo .css no me lo reconoce.

En el html estoy haciendo la referencia al css asi:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/main.css">
```

Y en la hoja de estilos, el botón tiene lo siguiente:

```
#btn-back-to-top {
     position: fixed !important;
     bottom: 20px !important;
     right: 20px !important;
     display: none !important;
}
```

Este es  el boton:

```
       <button
              type="button"
              class="btn btn-secondary"
              id="btn-back-to-top"
                >
      <i class="fas fa-arrow-up"></i>
      </button>
```

Ya intenté cambiarle la ruta relativa a ruta fija, o marcarle como `!important` a los estilos en el .css y nada, no funciona. En cambio dentro del `<head>` si funciona.

Para mi es más un problema de los estilos, ya que probé dándole a otros elementos (como por ejemplo a una tabla) desde el mismo .css y funciona bien.

Estas son las rutas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: inspecciona el botón en el navegador y verifica si otro estilo esta chocando con el tuyo o si de plano tu estilo no aparece en la inspección, ya que debería aparecer pero tachado.

Comment: Inspeccionándolo, ni me aparece la referencia por Id (#btn-back-to-top)

Comment: prueba referenciarlo por medio de una clase

Comment: Tampoco aparece en el inspeccionar con una clase.

Comment: intenta usar <a> en lugar del  <button> para validar si es el elemento el del problema,  esto tomando en cuenta que tu archivo css esta correctamente referenciado en al html

Comment: Si lo cambio por una etiqueta <a>, aparece igual que como si fuese el botón.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137576/discussion-between-henry-marca-zeballos-and-bilbit-bolson).

Comment: Hola, si nos muestras cual es tu ruta de tu archivo HTML y la de tu archivo CSS sería excelente. Por otra parte, prueba ejecutando tu código en el navegador en modo incognito o ventana privada si usas firefox

Comment: Para llamar a **Main.css** desde tu **HTML**, debería ser algo así: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../wwwroot/css/main.css">`